# Unable to find symbol in installed (GRASS GIS) libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, dynamic-linking

Using  pybind11, I'm trying to interface with a modified `r.viewshed` source code (copied into my source directory for now). However, when I try to  import  the  function in python I get

```bash
package.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN16mm_register_initD1Ev
```

Inspecting the `so` file:

```bash
$ nm -D package.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so| grep mm_register_init
                 U _ZN16mm_register_initC1Ev
                 U _ZN16mm_register_initD1Ev
```

With `U` meaning  that the symbol is undefined  (see `man  nm`).

Checking if any `libgrass` files that are visibile by `ldconfig` contain the symbol draws a blank too,  as well as checking every `.so` file on the filesystem.

```bash
ldconfig -p  | grep -o "/opt/grass/.*" | xargs nm -D | grep mm_register_init
# and
fd "libgrass" / -e so | xargs nm -D | grep mm_register_init
```

Calling `grass` launches grass without an issue.

The only solution I can see is adding the source code as a submodule and statically linking every required function which is not what I'd like to do.